# Initializing vector of vectors using assignment operator

Tags: c++, vector, instantiation, assignment-operator

I have a class that declares a vector of vectors in a `.h` header file as follows:

```
#include <vector>
    
class Mapper {
    public:
        ...
        Mapper(const uint num_rows, const uint num_cols, const double initial_val);
        ...
    private:
        ...
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> grid_map_;
        ...
};
```

And the definition of the `Mapper` class is implemented in a corresponding `.cpp`. However, I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to initialize the `grid_map_` vector of vectors in the `Mapper` constructor using the assignment operator notation similar to what's shown below:

```
Mapper::Mapper(const uint num_rows, const uint num_cols, const double initial_val) {
    ...
    grid_map_ = std::vector<vector<double>>(num_rows, num_cols, initial_val);
    ...
}
```

I know I can initialize it as follows,

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> vec(num_rows, std::vector<double>(num_cols, initial_val));
grid_map_ = vec;
```

or I could also use an initializer list, however, I'm trying to avoid those two methods. Is such a thing possible?

What I'm trying to do is similar to declaring a custom type in the `.h`, and then instantiating it in the constructor using assignment operator notation. For example in the header you'd have:

```
Object object_;
```

and then in the `.cpp` file you'd have:

```
object_ = Object();
```

Is initializing a vector of vectors in this way possible?

Comment: You know all the pieces. Just combine them: `grid_map_ = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(num_rows, std::vector<double>(num_cols, initial_val));` Better still, initialize `grid_map_` in constructor initializer list.

Comment: Don't use nested vectors for square data at scale. They have loads of overhead and you don't need them. Make yourself a nice vector of _num_rows × num_cols_ `double`s instead. As a bonus, you probably already know the quick, easy way to initialise one of those!

Comment: By the way, as it sounds like you haven't heard of it, you should be [initialising members in the member initialiser list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1711990/4386278) as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answers @AsteroidsWithWings, I mentioned an initializer in my post, but I'm trying to avoid it simply for aesthetic reasons (even though it can be more efficient afaik).

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings, do you have a source showing the overhead of using nested vectors, I'd be interested to read more.

Comment: First of all you have many allocations instead of one big allocation. Second: Your data will not be in one continuous chunk of memory. Instead it will be scattered which gives you worse cache locality. Third: Every time you access an element, the processor will have to dereference two pointers instead of one (so-called pointer chasing) which should take longer than just calculating the linear index like ```grid_map_[row * num_cols + col]```. This is called lexic indexing.

Comment: Frustratingly it is much easier to find sources about working with nested vectors than finding sources about them being a performance sin when trying to implement a matrix. But if you have an idea about the implementation of ```vector``` and about modern processor architecture, it is very clear that nesting them is bad.

Comment: @indigoblue What you showed in your post is not initialization.

Comment: What's better: a wallet that contains 100 wallets that each have $1 in them, or a wallet that has $100 in it?